# Referencing xsd type under no namespace in WADL document

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsd, wadl

I'm trying to describe my REST service using WADL document (Customer's requirement).

The service is pretty simple. There are no input parameters, the output is simple user object

WADL Document for this service

```
<application 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02 wadl.xsd" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
    <grammars>
        <include href="user.xsd" />
    </grammars>
    <resources base="http://localhost:8000/">
        <resource path="users">
            <method name="GET" id="UserGet">
                <request />
                <response status="200">
                    <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="User" />
                </response>
            </method>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</application>
```

XSD document, that describes User type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="User" nillable="true" type="User" />
  <xs:complexType name="User">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Using the WADL document, SOAP UI doesn't recognize User reference in Response tag and thus is not able to find it in attached user.xsd.

Question:

How do I provide a reference to type, that doesn't live under any namespace in xsd file, in WADL document?

Thanks